# Firebase phone auth in .net

Tags: .net, firebase, firebase-authentication

Couldn't find a .net package that supports Firebase phone auth in .net.

Neither do I see the endpoint in the REST docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/

Any advice how we can do the implementation in .net (.net 5 and .net framework)?

For context, the official docs is based on JavaScript SDK.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth

Or is the reason there's not backend SDK because the implementation is meant to be exposed in frontend?